# Jquery mobile and mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, touch, mouseover

I want that when I move the mouse on a label I alert("something"), I have tried many functions but always the alert only works when I click on the label and not when I just move it on the label!!
I have tried:

```
$("#show").mouseover(function(){
   alert("something");
});
```

---

```
$("#show").mouseenter(function(){
   alert("something");
});
```

---

```
$("#show").live('vmouseover', function() {
   alert("something");
});
```

---

```
$("#show").hover(
  function () {
     alert("something");
});
```

Comment: As @Jivings says, mouse events doesn't work on mobile, you are searching for an alternate touching event.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the mobile specific virtual events that jQuery-Mobile provides. Their descriptions can be found here:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

In particular, you are asking for mouseover:

```
$("#show").vmouseover(function(){
   alert("something");
});
```

Comment: @Bouaziz And you've tested it on a mobile device?

Comment: @Bouaziz When are you expecting it to fire? The emulator wont catch a simple mouseover the element. And on an Android device when is there ever a `mouseover`? You either touch an element or swipe it.