# cascading menu with jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, hover

I would like to create a cascading menu for an mvc 4 app. So far I have this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b">
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Workstations", "Index", "ClientAddresses")</li>
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Leads", "Index", "Leads")</li>
    <li>Targets
        <ul>
             <li> ...Target for product 1... </li>
             <li> ...Target for product 2... </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Log out", "LogOut", "Login")</li>
</ul>
```

So I would like it when I hover over the item "Targets" the other list to open next to it. How can this be done? Thanks

Comment: "So I would like it when I hover over the item"...so I would prefer hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the `Grouped collapsible with listviews` http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/accordions/

Comment: `jQuery Mobile` is designed for mobile devices, so I think `hover` event on mobile devices is a bad design. I agree that `jQuery Mobile` is also designed and fully tested to work not just on mobile phones, so you can use `jQuery` to handle the `hover` event as you want.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S4 has hover, and I think there are other devices with hover too already

Comment: yes, some tablets with stylus too, "bad design" depends on context, I think the best way to handle `hover` event is by using `jquery`

Comment: ok, thanks, I will mark yours as answer and vote it up, cause in general, probably this would be the best approach, though I would like seeing, even when I click, the child list coming out at the right of the parent, guess that then can be done with the standard css method?

Comment: yes, of course. Also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696533/jquery-hover-event-on-a-tag-on-mobile-devices and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904868/jquery-mobile-and-mouseover-event